# Axis 2 client sets http header protocol of "POST /SOAP/ HTTP/1.1" which is problematic

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, xmlbeans

I'm have written an Axis2 client with XMLBeans binding and everything seems to work fine as far as creating the soap message. However, the http header has the protocol set to "POST /SOAP/ HTTP/1.1" (see debug logging below) which is causing the service provider to raise this error - **Runtime extension for protocol 'SOAP/' not found**

I couldn't find anything that i can configure within axis to not add /SOAP/ to the protocol, would appreciate any pointers!

I would rather not ask the service provider to address this issue and ideally would want to address this on the client side (by the way, the request works just fine using SoapUI).

2012/09/21 10:02:42:955 PDT [DEBUG] header - >> "**POST /SOAP/ HTTP/1.1**[\r][\n]"

Comment: Update to the original question - SOAP UI has the protocol as such - Fri Sep 21 10:58:42 PDT 2012:DEBUG:>> "POST /SOAP HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" So the problem here is the forward slash after SOAP/ How can i get axis to not add this forward slash?

Comment: This is resolved.. /SOAP/ seemed to me like a specification of the protocol. In fact it was a part of the url i was hitting and i just had to remove the trailing / there..